# Access URLs in the Window's History Object

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

Is there any way to randomly access the URLs in Javascript's `History` object in Safari? I'm writing an extension where I need to, on a specifically-formatted page request, capture the URL of the previous page. From what I've been able to find, the `History` object definition is non-standard across browsers. Safari only seems to expose its `length` property and the standard methods that actually *move* within the history. Where other implementations expose `current`, `previous` and `next` properties, I can't see anything that tells me Safari does the same.

I've also tried `document.referrer`, but that doesn't appear to get populated in this case.

I just need to display the previously accessed URL on a given page. Is there any other way to access that URL?

Thanks.

Comment: What if the user typed in the URL? or came from a bookmark?

Comment: In this case, it can't (or at the very least is highly unlikely to) happen. I'm capturing a click on Safari's RSS button in the address bar. You have to be on a page to click that button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this, at least in any white-hat way. By design. You can step the user backward and forward, but you can't see the URLs.

Less scrupulous script-writers have of course taken this as a challenge. I believe the closest they've come is to dynamically write a bunch of known comparison links to the page, and then inspect them to see if they're showing in the "visited" color state. Perhaps if you're working in a closed and predictable environment (an intranet app?), with a known set of URLs, this might be a valid approach for you. Then again, in such an environment you could deal with this on the server side with session management.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, Mozilla (and others?) expose a `previous` member that would do _exactly_ what I'm after. Unfortunately, that does me no good in a Safari/WebKit environment so it appears that the answer is...you can't. I'm going to avoid crazy hacks and just forego the feature I was working on for a while.

Comment: Rob, you're right about `previous`, but only in the very special case where the user is running a cryptographically signed script with `UniversalBrowserRead` privileges granted -- and of course only in Mozilla...